How to fix axis label for 3D graph in Python?
enter image description here
I have here a 3D scatter plot with a plane running through it. I made it in Python. It's perfect except for one thing. There is this really annoying 1e7 up near the top that I don't want in there. It is meant to represent the z axis and the scale of the numbers on that side (for example, 2.5 on the z axis is actually 2.5*10^7 which is actually 25000000). I can't figure out how to get rid of the 1e7 though because it makes the graph look off. I was thinking of either having the z axis just show the large scale numbers (25000000), or keep the smaller scale numbers and just add 10^7 to the label with the "kg CO2". Does anyone know how to get rid of that 1e7? I'll provide my code below.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    def planeFit( x, y, z ):
    z = 1035.09 * x + 428.68 * y - 216274.07
    N = len(x)
    xbar = sum(x) / N
    ybar = sum(y) / N
    zbar = sum(z) / N
    Sxx = sum(x * x) / N - xbar * xbar
    Syy = sum(y * y) / N - ybar * ybar
    Sxy = sum(x * y) / N - xbar * ybar
    Sxz = sum(x * z) / N - xbar * zbar
    Syz = sum(y * z) / N - ybar * zbar
    denominator = Sxx * Syy - Sxy ** 2
    a = (Syy * Sxz - Sxy * Syz) / denominator
    b = (Sxx * Syz - Sxy * Sxz) / denominator
    c = zbar - a * xbar - b * ybar
    return a, b, c
x = np.array( [ 940.5, 971.5, 1017, 1221.5, 1263, 1305, 1629, 1663, 1703, 4915, 4981, 5141, 6459, 6452, 6596, 8493, 8540, 8698, 9079, 9107.5, 9463.5, 11877.5, 11895.5, 6594.5, 15700, 15803.5, 15448.5, 14136.5, 14098.5, 14272.5, 18596.5, 18384.5, 18573, 24831.5, 24780, 24036, 20028, 19991, 19614.5, 25418.5, 25277.5, 19286.5, 25812.5, 25914.5, 25841, 405, 488.5, 601.5, 1881.5, 283, 2781, 3577.5, 4366, 5402.5, 5701.5, 7179, 8745.5, 8675.5, 12502.5, 10066 ] )
y = np.array( [ 500, 500, 500, 750, 750, 750, 1000, 1000, 1000, 2500, 2500, 2500, 3750, 3750, 3750, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4500, 4500, 4500, 6750, 6750, 6750, 9000, 9000, 9000, 7000, 7000, 7000, 10500, 10500, 10500, 14000, 14000, 14000, 9500, 9500, 9500, 14250, 14250, 14250, 19000, 19000, 19000, 500, 750, 1000, 2500, 3750, 5000, 4500, 6750, 9000, 7000, 10500, 14000, 9500, 14250, 19000 ] )
z = np.array( [ 1150000, 1200000, 1270000, 1590000, 1660000, 1740000, 2210000, 2290000, 2370000, 5890000, 5980000, 6170000, 8170000, 8190000, 8370000, 11200000, 11300000, 11500000, 10800000, 10900000, 11300000, 14900000, 15000000, 9330000, 20500000, 20700000, 20300000, 16900000, 16800000, 17100000, 23400000, 23200000, 23400000, 32300000, 32300000, 31500000, 23800000, 23800000, 23400000, 31900000, 31700000, 25300000, 35300000, 35500000, 35400000, 546000, 732000, 985000, 2670000, 3610000, 5120000, 4940000, 6440000, 8670000, 7580000, 10500000, 13900000, 11600000, 15400000, 21100000 ] )
a, b, c = planeFit( x, y, z )
fmt = "{:8.3f} "
print ( "Best fit a, b, c = ", (3 * fmt).format( a, b, c ) )
zfit = a * x + b * y + c
print( "Values x, y, z, zfit:" )
for i in range( len( x ) ):
    print((4 * fmt).format(x[i], y[i], z[i], zfit[i]))

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot( projection='3d' )
ax.scatter( x, y, z, color='r' )
x1d = np.linspace( min( x ), max( x ), 5 )
y1d = np.linspace( min( y ), max( y ), 5 )
x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid( x1d, y1d )
zplane = a * x2d + b * y2d + c
ax.plot_surface( x2d, y2d, zplane, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.3 )
ax.set_xlabel('Frame weight (Tons)')
ax.set_ylabel('GFA/L (feet)')
ax.set_zlabel('GWP (kg CO2)')
plt.show()


If you want to add it to your label you can simply divide your z data by 1e7:
z /= 1e7  # you can do this because z is a numpy.ndarray

Or if you don't want to alter z itself, divide it when passing it to the plotting function.
ax.scatter(x, y, z/1e7, color="r")

And update your axis label:
ax.set_zlabel("GWP (kg CO2/1e7)")

